# How can I strip the base url in Nginx for a Mojolicious app?

Tags: perl, nginx, mojolicious

I am trying to run a Mojolicious up as a reverse proxy. My Nginx configuration looks like this:

```
upstream printo {
    server 127.0.0.1:3000;
}

[..]

location /print {
   proxy_pass http://printo;
   proxy_http_version 1.1;
   proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
   proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
   proxy_set_header Host $host;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
```

I'd like to strip the `/printo` portion of the URL before the request reaches the Mojolicious app - otherwise, all the requests have a `/printo/something` URL, which results in a 404.

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43290656/mojolicious-is-not-capturing-url-only-base-url) but I'd like to do it in Nginx if possible.

I've tried rewrite like this:

```
rewrite ^/print/(.+)$ $1;
```

to no result.

How's that done?

Comment: Is this question really anything to do with Perl or Mojolicious? It looks like you're asking about an Apache configuration problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To modify the URI as it passes upstream, you can use a `rewrite...break` or perform a similar function using the `proxy_pass` directive itself.

For example:

```
location /print {
    rewrite ^/print(/.*)$ $1 break;
    proxy_pass http://printo;
    ...
}
```

Remember to keep a leading `/` in the rewritten URI. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.
Or:

```
location /print/ {
    proxy_pass http://printo/;
    ...
}
```

The `location` value should have a trailing `/` to ensure that the text substitution occurs correctly. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) for details.

Comment: The second example works. I didn't manage to make the first one. @richard-smith